# Using theme palette colors in custom MUI component variants with light/dark mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For readability reasons, I want to split the `components` object passed in the `createTheme` function (components may have large variants) and I do have light/dark mode.

According to [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#main-content), this is how we get the design tokens:

```
const getDesignTokens = (mode: PaletteMode) => ({
  palette: {
    mode,
    ...(mode === 'light'
      ? {
          // palette values for light mode
          primary: amber,
          divider: amber[200],
          text: {
            primary: grey[900],
            secondary: grey[800],
          },
        }
      : {
          // palette values for dark mode
          primary: deepOrange,
          divider: deepOrange[700],
          background: {
            default: deepOrange[900],
            paper: deepOrange[900],
          },
          text: {
            primary: '#fff',
            secondary: grey[500],
          },
        }),
  },
});
```

After that, I create the theme depending on whether the mode is light or dark.

The problem is when I'm trying to add a component to the theme (as stated before, each component will be only referenced in the `createTheme`, the definition would be somewhere else) I cannot use colors from the theme without wrapping the component is a function which has the parameter the mode used.

I wonder if there is any solution like with the `sx` prop when you're referencing the color as a string, let's say `sx={{ backgroundColor: 'button.background' }}` and that would automatically be used from the theme.

Wrapping each component in a function with a parameter does the job, but I would like to know if there is any better solution.

**How the code is now**:

```
const dashedVariants = (palette) => ({
  props: {variant: 'dashed'},
  style: {
    border: `1px dashed ${palette.dashColor}`
  }
})

const Button = (palette) => ({
  styleOverrides: {},
  variants: [dashedVariants(palette)]
})
```

vs what I'm trying to acheive:

```
const dashedVariants = {
  props: {variant: 'dashed'},
  style: {
    border: `1px dashed palette.dashColor` //something like that??
  }
}
```

**Note**: I've looked over [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845610/using-theme-palette-colors-in-custom-mui-button-variant), but unfortunately this does seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Due to complexity of CSS properties, many UI toolkit and its themes only parse singular properties(or provide a detour utility); MUI's one of them. Use separate border properties to make parser working. Palette color property parser only works for the type of `React.CSSProperties['color']` property. `.border` property is `Property.Border` type. The color parser won't work in this case.
2. `Palette` type [only works with appropriate properties](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#customization). it does not provide `dashColor` property. according to MUI doc, working properties are:

```
.palette.primary.light
.palette.primary.main
.palette.primary.dark
.palette.primary.contrastText
// ...
.palette.secondary
.palette.error
.palette.warning
.palette.info
.palette.success
```

```js
const theme = {
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: '#...' // user defiend color
    }
  }
}

const dashedVariants = {
  props: {variant: 'dashed'},
  style: {
    borderColor: 'secondary.main',
    borderWidth: '1px',
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
  }
}
```

3. There's an [experimental CSS variable feature](https://mui.com/experimental-api/css-variables/). With this, it is possible to define CSS variable inside complex property. This is probably the closest to the goal but it's currently experimental stage, might be unstable for production use. I am also looking forward to using this in the future.

Comment: about `dashColor`, it was just an example + it was added to the theme.
My only issue is that neither something like `secondary.main` work. I know about the CSS variables feature, but since it's not stable I'm not going to use it yet.